# Bootstrap's sticky top causes navbar to not be scrollable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can decide between either using sticky-top (or fixed-top) or my Navbar being scrollable on a mobile device. Meaning that whenever I add sticky-top the scrolling functionality disappears or when I give the scrolling a higher priority, the navbar is not sticking to the top anymore. I got another object above the navbar, that's why I'd like to use Bootstrap's sticky-top functionality.

I tried different approaches to making my navbar scrollable and different approaches to make my navbar sticky, but they didn't work together. It wasn't scrollable until I wrapped the entire nav in another div.

My navbar looks like this:

```html
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid jumbotron_custom" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
<h1><a href="index.html">Some Text</a></h1>
</div>

<div class="sticky-top nav-wrapper">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-dark navbar-default">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
    data-target="#collapsingNavbar">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="collapsingNavbar">
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

and the relevant code in my Custom CSS File looks like this:

```css
@media (max-width: 1199.98px) {
  .navbar-wrapper{
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

I'm using Bootstrap 4

I want the Navbar to always be sticky while having the scrolling functionality on mobile devices.